# Inputs to alias vs. functions in shell script

Tags: shell

Why doesn't the alias work, but the function does works inside my .bash_profile?

Code inside .bash_profile (below)

```
alias pxsz='sips -g pixelWidth $1 && sips -g pixelHeight $1'

pxlsz () {
    sips -g pixelWidth $1 && sips -g pixelHeight $1
}
```

When I tested the alias with

```
alias pxsz="echo '$1 1' && echo '$1 2' "
```

gives

```
 $pxsz tag_struct.jpg
1
2 tag_struct.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable inside an alias like this. Here you just call to the `$1` that must be defined beforehand in your shell, and it is the previous first argument of previous command:

```
$ set TEST
$ echo $1
TEST
$ alias pxsz="echo '$1 1' && echo '$1 2' "
$  pxsz
TEST 1
TEST 2
```

**The function, like you did, is the way to go**.